# Combine a LdapUser and AppUserModel to create a global User

Tags: java, structure

I have to make an application for my enterprise that provide an Authentication by Active Directory (ldap).
My app can contain users that don't have a ldap account (temp users like for a interim), so we can create a custom user in my app database.

> LdapUser.java

```
public class LdapUser {
    private String forname;
    private String lastname;
    private byte[] avatar;
}
```

> UserModel.java

```
@Entity
@Data
public class UserModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String data;
}
```

So, users using ldap won't have a password in database, and the other ones will.

When someone tries to connect to my app, I first retrieve the `LdapUser` object from ldap. If the user does not exist, I'll load an `UserModel` by username/password. And if the user exists, I'll load by username.

**EDIT: At this point**, be sure you understood that a ldapUser have informations in database too. That is to say a ldapUser will have the application related informations in database too, and a non ldap-user won't have LdapUser class informations (logic).

**Now my problematic** I would like to know the cleaner way to combine `UserModel` and `LdapUser` to create an `AuthenticatedUser` which can have an nullable `LdapUser` and all `UserModel` methods.

I tried first with the following template

```
@Getter
public final class AuthenticatedUser extends UserModel {
    private final Optional<LdapUser> ldap;

    public static AuthenticatedUser of(@Nullable LdapUser ldapUser, UserModel user) {
        AuthenticatedUser auth = new AuthenticatedUser(ldapUser);
        auth.setId(user.getId());
        auth.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        auth.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        auth.setData(user.getData());
        return auth;
    }

    private AuthenticatedUser(LdapUser ldapUser)
    {
        this.ldap = Optional.ofNullable(ldapUser);
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if this way is bad, cause each modification on `UserModel` will force me to update the static method `AuthenticatedUser of(@Nullable Utilisateur ldapUser, User user)`. And by this way, we create a second instance of `UserModel` from a first one, I don't find it that clean. Do you? Is there any known pattern for this, or any improved idea?